# kafkaendpointlistenerregistry.start() throws null pointer exception

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, autowired, spring-kafka

I have a requirement where I want to start Kakfa consumer manually.

Code :

```
class    Dummy implements    
        ConsumerSeekAware
{

@Autowired     
KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

CountDownLatch latch;

@Autowired    
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory     factory;

onIdleEvent(){
    latch.countdown()
}       
@KafkaListener(id="myContainer", 
   topics="mytopic",  
  autoStartup="false")    
public void listen() {}


@Scheduled(cron=" some time ")
    void do_some_consumption(){

latch = new CountDownLatch(1);    
this.registry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").start();    
    latch.await();
        do processing


   this.registry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").stop()

}
}
```

I have made the bean of 
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory with all props in my other Config class which I am Autowiring here.

However, I get a null pointer exception when I start my container 
using this.registry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").start()

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Add the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: @GaryRussell edited!

Comment: That's not very useful; if you can post a small, complete, project someplace that exhibits this behavior, I can take a lookl.

Comment: The only other thing I am using is a Config class with consumerfactory<String, String> and   Bean definition ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String,String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {} which I am Autowiring in DummyClass.

Answer (score 2):

I just copied your code into a Spring Boot app (which auto configures the factories); and everything works perfectly as expected...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class So62412316Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So62412316Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("mytopic", "foo");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("mytopic").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}

@Component
class Dummy implements ConsumerSeekAware {

    @Autowired
    KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    CountDownLatch latch;

    @Autowired
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory;

    @EventListener
    public void onIdleEvent(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "myContainer", topics = "mytopic", autoStartup = "false")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 5_000, fixedDelay = 60_000)
    void do_some_consumption() throws InterruptedException {

        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        this.registry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").start();
        latch.await();

        this.registry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").stop();
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.idle-event-interval=5000
```

Comment: Thanks for trying out Gary ! But, what if I want to define a bean of Consumer and Container Factory in some other class holding all props related to brokers, SSL and topic ? Do I need to provide some other configuration so that the registry in dummy class registers my container factory in Config class ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; it doesn't matter where the factory `@Bean`s are declared as long as they exist. It's also not clear why you are auto wiring `factory`. As I said, your `Dummy` class works as expected for me (no NPE). If you can post a small, complete project someplace that exhibits this behavior, I can see what you are doing wrong.