# How do we know we reached the last message in the kafka topic using KafkaMessageListenerContainer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am running consumer using KafkaMessageListenerContainer.I need to stop the consumer on the topic's last message.How can i identify particular message is the last message in the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with the following shell command (remove `--partition` parameter to get offsets for all topic's partitions):

```sh
./bin/kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list <host>:<port> --topic <topic-name> --partition <partition-number> --time -1
```

As you can see, this is using the `GetOffsetShell` [0] object that you may use to get the last message offset and compare it with record's offset.

[0] https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/GetOffsetShell.scala

Comment: I need  to get end offset when i am using KafkaMessageListenerContainer from spring-kafka

Comment: I don't think there is any API for that in KafkaMessageListenerContainer. So you'll have to figure out how to use the object I mentiond or the CLI command from your Java code.

Comment: Got the answer from here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62390164/10305656

Comment: yep, that's a more convenient way